# (android)How to write code to check a file in a folder

Tags: java, android, file, android-file

I have a music.mp3 file in "/Android/data/Myfolder" and I would like to write code to check that if there is music.mp3 file in the Myfolder.Now, I dont know how to write code about that.

Comment: stackoverflow is not code writing service, please help yourself first and google is your friend, we you stuck at any stage, ask and you will get all the help.

Comment: `"/Android/data/Myfolder"`. That folder /Android/data does not exist. Not on a single device. Please first find out the real path. You have to use the full path anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `File` class `exists()` method like this :-

```
  String folderPath = "/Android/data/Myfolder";
        String fileName = "music.mp3";
        File music = new File(folderPath+"/"+fileName);
        if(music.exists()){ // return true if found
            System.out.println(fileName +"found");
            // other found logics here
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(fileName +" not found here");
            // other not found logics here
        }
```